# {Solved} Next.Js 13.4: Dyanamic Metadata is not displaying when shared or with other tools

Tags: next.js, vercel

In my published site when i go to dynamic routes pages and share the site in social media or just checking my SEO in tools with "https://metatags.io/" its not displaying, but when i go through lighhouse developer settings or inspect elements in google developer tools the metadata is present. For the static pages everything working great from title to og images.

My Code
Next JS: 13.4.5 (upgrading as soon as new version relesing hoping its a bug)

***Live page***
**https://anudeepsambaraju.com/post/opinion-ai-chatgpt**

**post/[slug]**

```
async function getPost(slug) {
  const url = config.apiUrl;
  const apiKey = config.apiKey;
  const res = await fetch(`${url}/blog/post/${slug}?api_key=${apiKey}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 3600 },
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch the data");
  }
  return await res.json();
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params }) {
  const slug = params.slug;
  const post = await getPost(slug);
  return {
    title: post.postData.title,
    description: post.postData.seoDescription,
    alternates: {
      canonical: `post/${post.postData.slug}`,
    },
    openGraph: {
      title: post.postData.title,
      description: post.postData.seoDescription,
      url: `post/${post.postData.slug}`,
      siteName: "",
      images: [
        {
          url: `${post.postData.seoImage}`,
          width: 300,
          height: 50,
          alt: "Blog Post",
        },
      ],
    },
  };
}
```

**layout.js**

```
export const metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL('https://anudeepsambaraju.com'),
  title: {
    default: "xxxx",
    template: '%s | Anudeep Sambaraju',
  },
  description: {
    default: `xxxxx`,
  },
  alternates: {
    canonical: `/`,
  },
  openGraph: {
    title: 'xxxxx`,
    url: `/`,
    siteName: 'xxxx',
  },
  creator: 'xxxx',
  publisher: 'xxxx',
  authors: [{ name: 'xxxx' }],
}
```

............................

**It solved after minor changes**

First, I have updated to the next 13.4.6 still the issue is not solved, After some trial and error and reading the changelog
I have removed some code in the Social share component which is in the dynamic Page

```
export default function SocialShare() {
    // const currentPage = window.location.href;
    const currentPage = 'https://topbestmovie.com';
  return (
    <div className='pl-2 py-6 space-x-3' >
    <WhatsappShareButton url={currentPage} quote="Please Share the Post" >
        <WhatsappIcon size={35} round={true} />
    </WhatsappShareButton>
```

commenting "window.location.href" worked yes not i cant share current page, and i don't know why it clashing with metadata, anyhow it solved hope anyone found itself helpful